# A number is randomly chosen in interval 1 to 3. what is prob that first digit to right of decimal is 5

Tags: probability, probability-theory, uniform-distribution

> A number is randomly chosen in interval 1 to 3. what is prob that first digit to right of decimal is 5

My attempt:

1.0, 1.1 ....3.0 --> total there are 21 digits

favourable outcomes = 1.5, 2.5 --> means there are 2 favourable outcomes.

so required probability = 2/21 = 0.095

But in textbook, he assumed it as uniform distribution and solved it(then the ans = .1). When to apply which distribution, how to interpret? Please elaborate

Comment: I don't understand your calculation at all. Neither $1.5$ nor $2.5$ are between $0$ and $1$.  And, of course, there are infinitely many real numbers between $.5$ and $.6$   To solve the problem note that "random" implies that digit in each place is equally likely to be any of the en candidates.

Comment: As to which distribution is relevant here, that is up to whomever set the problem.  Absent information to the contrary, I would have assumed that "random" meant "uniformly random".  If something else was intended, it should have been specified.

Comment: sir made a mistake while typing. Apologise for the inconvinience.Pls have a look now

Comment: Ok, so now $1.5$ and $2.5$ are in the interval, but so is, say, $1.51$ or $2.53079$ or...well, as you can see, there are infinitely many possible values.  You won't get anywhere by counting.

Comment: If you want to just use the standard definition of a uniform distribution, ask: what is the probability that our selection is between $1.5$ and $1.6$ OR between $2.5$ and $2.6$.  Those are the "good" values (well, other than $1.6, 2.6$).

Comment: Understood sir. Thank you.

Comment: The problem is when you say "$1.0, 1.1, \ldots ,3.0 \to $ total there are $21$ digits". If that had been $20$ then you would get the correct answer, since the probability of choosing a number starting $3.0\ldots$ is zero

Comment: Same as the probability that a two digit number between 10 (inclusive) and 30 (exclusive) ends in a 5. So 2 out of 20, or 0.1, and this does assume uniform probability.  We dont include the 30 as an endpoint, so what looks like 2/21 is actually 2/20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we only care about the number immediately to the right of the decimal place, we can just look at the range $[0,1)$ instead of $[1,3)$. (The choice of including the endpoints is kind of irrelevant since it makes a difference of 1 number when there are infinite numbers in any range. I picked it the way I did so the process for finding the answer is simpler).

Consider the following number in that range:

$$0.2748191\dotsm$$

Notice how we can make a similar looking number that does fit the requirements:

$$0.5748191\dotsm$$

In fact, for any combination of digits after the first digit after the decimal point, you can make 10 numbers by changing the number after the decimal point.

$$0.0748191\dotsm$$
$$0.1748191\dotsm$$
$$0.2748191\dotsm$$
$$0.3748191\dotsm$$
$$0.4748191\dotsm$$
$$0.5748191\dotsm$$
$$0.6748191\dotsm$$
$$0.7748191\dotsm$$
$$0.8748191\dotsm$$
$$0.9748191\dotsm$$

You’ll see that only **1 out of 10 possibilities** satisfy the requirement of having a 5 immediately after the decimal point. Therefore, you get the answer $0.1$

Comment: Sir in this approach 0.5XXX probability = 0.1. But in given interval it can be 1.5xxxx or 2.5xxxxxx . It implies, 0.1+0.1 = 0.2 probability. Am i missing something here???

Comment: @NascimentodeCos there are also twice as many ones that fail. You also would have 1.2xxxxx and 2.2xxxxxx. 1.7xxxxxx and 2.7xxxxxx etc.

Comment: understood sir. Simply beautiful approach :)